# how to make part of list item selectable and other not selectable wpf

Tags: c#, .net, wpf

how to make part of list item selectable wpf and other not selectable

I have an list view can select and unselect item in its and want when unselect its by part of the item

Class for Select and unselect items in list view

```
public static class ListBoxSelectionBehavior
    {
        public static readonly DependencyProperty ClickSelectionProperty =
            DependencyProperty.RegisterAttached("ClickSelection",
                                                typeof(bool),
                                                typeof(ListBoxSelectionBehavior),
                                                new UIPropertyMetadata(false, OnClickSelectionChanged));

        public static bool GetClickSelection(DependencyObject obj)
        {
            return (bool)obj.GetValue(ClickSelectionProperty);
        }

        public static void SetClickSelection(DependencyObject obj, bool value)
        {
            obj.SetValue(ClickSelectionProperty, value);
        }

        private static void OnClickSelectionChanged(DependencyObject dpo, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
        {
            ListView listBox = dpo as ListView;
            if (listBox != null)
            {
                if ((bool)e.NewValue == true)
                {
                    listBox.SelectionMode = SelectionMode.Multiple;
                    listBox.SelectionChanged += OnSelectionChanged;
                }
                else
                {
                    listBox.SelectionChanged -= OnSelectionChanged;
                }
            }
        }

        static void OnSelectionChanged(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
        {
            if (e.AddedItems.Count > 0)
            {
                ListView listBox = sender as ListView;
                var valid = e.AddedItems[0];
                foreach (var item in new ArrayList(listBox.SelectedItems))
                {
                    if (item != valid)
                    {
                        listBox.SelectedItems.Remove(item);
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Class for an extention of wrap panel to add discription and every items

```cs
    public class WrapPaneEx : WrapPanel
    {
        protected override Size ArrangeOverride(Size finalSize)
        {
            var size = base.ArrangeOverride(finalSize);

            foreach (UIElement fe in this.Children)
            {
                var itemLocation = GetItemLocation(fe);
                if (itemLocation == null)
                {
                    itemLocation = new ItemLocation(this, fe);
                    SetItemLocation(fe, itemLocation);
                }
                itemLocation.OnLocationPropertyChanged();
            }
            return size;
        }

        public static ItemLocation GetItemLocation(DependencyObject obj)
        {
            return (ItemLocation)obj.GetValue(ItemLocationProperty);
        }

        public static void SetItemLocation(DependencyObject obj, ItemLocation value)
        {
            obj.SetValue(ItemLocationProperty, value);
        }

        public static readonly DependencyProperty ItemLocationProperty = DependencyProperty.RegisterAttached("ItemLocation", typeof(ItemLocation), typeof(WrapPaneEx), new PropertyMetadata(null));
    }

    public class ItemLocation : INotifyPropertyChanged
    {
        public ItemLocation(Panel panel, UIElement itemContainer)
        {
            this._Panel = panel;
            this._ItemContainer = itemContainer;
        }

        private UIElement _ItemContainer;
        private Panel _Panel;

        public Point? Location
        {
            get
            {
                if (_Location == null && _Panel != null && _ItemContainer != null)
                {
                    _Location = _ItemContainer.TranslatePoint(default(Point), _Panel);
                }
                return _Location;
            }
        }
        private Point? _Location;

        public Point? LocationN
        {
            get
            {
                if (_LocationN == null && _Location == null && _Panel != null && _ItemContainer != null)
                {
                    Point? np = Location;
                    if (np != null)
                    {
                        _LocationN = new Point(-np.Value.X, -np.Value.Y);
                    }
                }
                return _LocationN;
            }
        }
        private Point? _LocationN;

        public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

        internal void OnLocationPropertyChanged()
        {
            _Location = null;
            _LocationN = null;
            PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(nameof(Location)));
            PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(nameof(LocationN)));
        }
    }
```

I hop when unselect item on list view to not be not selectable when click on the canvas of the details

```cs
<ScrollViewer  x:Name="scollviewer" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" >
                        <ListView x:Name="listview" Main:ListBoxSelectionBehavior.ClickSelection="True" HorizontalAlignment="Center" ItemsSource="{Binding Items}" SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedMovie}" PreviewMouseWheel="List_PreviewMouseWheel">
                                <ListView.Resources>
                                    <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type ListViewItem}" x:Key="withDetailTemplate">
                                        <Grid>
                                            <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                                                <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
                                                <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
                                            </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                                            <Border Grid.Row="0" x:Name="Bd" BorderBrush="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}" BorderThickness="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}" Background="{TemplateBinding Background}" Padding="0" SnapsToDevicePixels="true">
                                                <Grid>
                                                    <local:MovieListItemControl/>
                                                    <Border Background="White" Visibility="Collapsed"
                                    Height="2" Grid.RowSpan="2" x:Name="indicator"
                                    VerticalAlignment="Bottom"/>
                                                </Grid>
                                            </Border>
                                            <!-- **************** -->
                                            <Canvas Grid.Row="1" x:Name="detailCanvas" 
                                                Width="0" selec
                                                Height="{Binding ElementName=detailGrid,Path=ActualHeight}"
                                                HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Top" Visibility="Collapsed">
                                                <Grid x:Name="detailGrid" Width="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=FindAncestor,AncestorType={x:Type ScrollViewer},AncestorLevel=2},Path=ActualWidth}"
                                                   Canvas.Left="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=FindAncestor,AncestorType={x:Type ListViewItem}},Path=(local:WrapPaneEx.ItemLocation).LocationN.X}">
                                                    <local:MovieDetailsControl/>
                                                </Grid>
                                            </Canvas>
                                            <!-- **************** -->
                                        </Grid>
                                        <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                                            <Trigger Property="IsSelected" Value="true">
                                                <Setter Property="Background" TargetName="Bd" Value="Black"/>
                                                <Setter Property="Opacity" TargetName="Bd" Value="0.7"/>
                                                <Setter TargetName="indicator" Property="Visibility" Value="Visible"/>
                                                <Setter TargetName="detailCanvas" Property="Visibility" Value="Visible"/>

                                            </Trigger>
                                            <EventTrigger RoutedEvent="Loaded">
                                                <EventTrigger.Actions>
                                                    <BeginStoryboard>
                                                        <Storyboard>
                                                            <DoubleAnimation Storyboard.TargetProperty="Opacity" From="0" To="1" Duration="0:0:1" />
                                                        </Storyboard>
                                                    </BeginStoryboard>
                                                </EventTrigger.Actions>
                                            </EventTrigger>
                                        </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                                    </ControlTemplate>
                                </ListView.Resources>
                                <ListView.ItemContainerStyle>
                                    <Style TargetType="{x:Type ListViewItem}">
                                        <Setter Property="Template" Value="{StaticResource withDetailTemplate}" />
                                    </Style>
                                </ListView.ItemContainerStyle>
                                <ListView.ItemsPanel>
                                    <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                                        <local:WrapPaneEx  HorizontalAlignment="Center" Width="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=FindAncestor,AncestorType={x:Type ScrollViewer},AncestorLevel=2},Path=ActualWidth}"/>
                                    </ItemsPanelTemplate>
                                </ListView.ItemsPanel>
                            </ListView>
                    </ScrollViewer>
```

[image for expected propgram](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hGF3q.jpg)

Comment: Could you give a code example of what you have right now? What have you tried and etc? What type of objects are inside the listView?

Comment: @vsarunov  I add some code there

Comment: Is it same part for select and unselect? Like a checkbox or togglebutton? Which you could template into something looks like something else. Make everything else hit test visible false. And is focussable false so you can't arrow or tab to it

Comment: it's don't work for focussable I tried its

Comment: Have you tried using `IsHitTestVisible="False"` instead ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to make some elements in your `ListView` be readonly, you should use the `IsHitTestVisible="False"` Property on the `ListViewIitem`. To put that into perspective one would create a style for the `ListViewIem` and then use `DataTrigger` to switch that off and on.

```
<Style TargetType="ListViewItem">
    <Style.Triggers>
        <DataTrigger Binding="Property" Value="False">
            <Setter Property="IsHitTestVisible" Value="False"/>
        </DataTrigger>
    </Style.Triggers>
</Style>
```

Because this is a `DependencyProperty` you could also directly Bind to that Property:

```
<Style TargetType="ListViewItem">
    <Setter Property="IsHitTestVisible" Value="{Binding Property}"/>
</Style>
```

[MSDN](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.uielement.ishittestvisible?view=netframework-4.8) explanation.
And here is brief explanation:

> Gets or sets a value that declares whether this element can possibly be returned as a hit test result from some portion of its rendered content. This is a dependency property.